# Windows 10 automatically disconnects network on screen lock

Tags: wireless-networking

My system: HP Omen running on Windows 10.

Last week there was a major upgrade to Windows 10 (either Wed or Thu, don't remember which). After that it developed the following very annoying habit.
I habitually lug my laptop to and fro work at a local university. At home I have my WiFi/broadband. At work I connect to Eduroam.

- It used to be the case that Windows 10 would automatically detect the presence of Eduroam network, and connect to it without prompting.
- It would only ask for my password when I had changed it.

But, after this update:

- Windows 10 still detects the presence of Eduroam.
- The option to automatically connect is checked (my Win10 is in Finnish, so I don't necessarily want to attempt ot mistranslate it).
- Next to the Eduroam icon in the list of available networks there is an ominous message "action required".
- Windows10 won't remember my login credentials to Eduroam.
- If I don't do anything with the laptop for 2 minutes, it puts on the Lock screen (ok, I guess), but even before unlocking it complains "password required", and the wireless connection is gone.
- University tech support cannot help.

In the "properties of a wireless connection" there is, in a tab "protection" there is an option titled "choose network authentication method". It says 
"Microsoft: Protecte EAP (PEAP)" under that there is a box "remember my credentials ...". That box is checked.

Any ideas?

Having to retype my credentials every time I go for coffee, or to restroom, is a pain. I feel like undoing this update :-(

My guess is that some option I can't figure out was reset as a part of that large update.

---

Update: There have been two more Windows updates since this problem appeared. Today the behavior has been back to normal. I don't know what those updates did. Nor do I know whether the update came from Microsoft or Hewlett-Packard.

Keeping my fingers crossed. If somebody who knows what those updates did, I will gladly upvote and accept even an educated guess.

Comment: Before trying anything else.  I would forget the network, the reconnect to the network, making sure I selected the option to remember the password

Comment: @Ramhound A) I have that box checked (fifth line from the bottom) B) Would that explain why Windows remembered the credentials last week, but not this wekk? I didn't change anything.

Comment: Try my suggestion.

Comment: I just got one more suggestion from the local tech support. The suggestion was to make Windows "forget" about Eduroam, and readd it. They provide a piece of software for dumb uni employees to configure it automatically. IIRC this special piece of SW was needed to add Eduroam in Win7-era as well.

Comment: I can’t help you unless you try my suggestion.  You made no mention of using third-party software to manage your network connections.  If your not using the built-in capabilities then, it’s very likely, the software is to blame for the behavior you describe

Comment: The reason I won’t be able to help is simple.  I am trying to determine if it’s one of several reasons, so I can submit an answer, to the cause of your problem.  If it’s caused software by answer would be entirely different compared to if it’s a adapter settings issue.  No, I won’t be writing an answer that covers every possible reason this behavior happens.

Comment: Sorry, another update came during my coffee break, and I was without access.

Comment: I will add a screen capture. Gimme a minute.

Comment: I have also forgotten this network, and rediscovered it. I need to wait to see if there are any changes. For what it's worth, the Windows update 20 minutes ago slightly changed the appearance of the dialogue box that pops up when I was rediscovering eduroam.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78847/discussion-between-ramhound-and-jyrki-lahtonen).

Comment: I wasn't asking if you had set it to remember the network password I ask if you had tried to forget the network, then reconnect to the network, and making sure to remember the password.

Comment: @Ramhound FWIW, the problem has reappeared periodically, irrespective of the laptop, more or less every time I am asked to update my password to my University network (which somehow automagically also gives me access to Eduroam). I consulted the local tech staff. Their "official" advice is now exactly what you also suggested. "Forget" the network, and let win10 find it anew. If you want to post that as an answer, I will accept it. Otherwise it may be best to simply delete this question. However, the view count of this page is surprisingly high, so may be there is a reason to keep this?